# Is the latest H2 (1.4.200) database still have Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: h2

Is it right forum to discuss the security issue of H2 database?  Is the latest H2 (1.4.200) database still has the security issues listed at link, https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=17893&product_id=45580&version_id=&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=2018&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=2&sha=4b0469c034ade604446d7ba13f215239fac896a3

Answer (score -1):

CVE-2018-14335 looks like a fake one. Older version of H2 were affected only when you explicitly configure access to H2 Console for everyone, by default it is restricted for local connections only (do you have untrusted local users on the same PC?) and documentation clearly describes that you need to protect your server from unauthorized access when you want to enable remote access. Unfortunately, people usually don't read the documentation.

CVE-2018-10054 is not about the H2, it is about insecure configuration of H2 in Datomic, it is fixed in Datomic 0.9.5697.

Many third-party products include insecure configuration of H2. To protect their users from such security issues, H2 since the version 1.4.198 doesn't allow access to sensitive features of H2 Console (including features used in these two vulnerabilities) without additional authentication, so these issues should be considered as resolved in these products too if they use a some recent version of H2.

However, your application should not have databases with weak passwords of `ADMIN` users and enabled remote access for everyone. H2 is not a secure container, users with `ADMIN` privileges have access to the JVM and possibly to your system by design. Don't give `ADMIN` privileges to untrusted people and applications; you can create users with normal privileges for them and grant them access only to necessary data.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.